# how Unit test methods of Kotlin class with private constructor, companion object and extending another class without mocking

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

My class is extending another class and has companion object and private constructor. I have to Unit test getLastKnownLocation() method. I dont want mock GpsTrackingService class and would like instantiate it in my test class. How I can do it? Thanks for any help, in advance

```
 class GpsTrackingService private constructor(private val context: Context, private val Snavigator: SNavigator?) : LocationListener {
    
        companion object {}
    
    getLastKnowLocation() {}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the constructor `internal`, mock the dependencies, and use them to instantiate your class.

```
class GpsTrackingServiceTest {
   
   private lateinit var context: Context
   private lateinit var sNavigator: SNavigator
   private lateinit var trackingService: GpsTrackingService

   @Before
   fun setup() {
      context = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
      sNavigator = Mockito.mock(SNavigator::class.java)
      trackingService = GpsTrackingService(context, sNavigator)
   }

   @Test
   fun test_getLastKnowLocation() {
      trackingService.getLastKnowLocation()
      // do your verifications, etc
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but GpsTrackingService in @Before fun setup() turns red and asks me to make init() public, which is possible only by removing private contructor

Comment: your code worked I just had to add getInstance after GpsTrackingService here trackingService = GpsTrackingService.getInstance(context, sNavigator)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
class GpsTrackingServiceTest {
   
   private lateinit var mContext: Context
   private lateinit var sNavigator: SNavigator
   private lateinit var trackingService: GpsTrackingService

   @Before
   fun setup() {
      cmContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
      sNavigator = Mockito.mock(SNavigator::class.java)
      trackingService = GpsTrackingService.getInstance(mContext, redNavigator)
   }

   @Test
   fun test_getLastKnowLocation() {
      trackingService.getLastKnowLocation()
      // do your verifications, etc
   }
}
```